# Is there a .NET IoC container that can load and unload assemblies

Tags: c#, mef, autofac

I'm beating my head against the wall trying to find a container that will accomplish this.

What I'd like to do is have a AS.NET website running and not unload / recycle the AppDomain when I deploy a new or updated business rule contained in an assembly. This implies that the folder is outside of the bin folder, and preferably above it, not under it (although I can live with that). The closet I've come to this so far is using Autofac and MEF, but it seems like there's no way to unload a previously loaded assembly.

Anybody have any resources they can point me to?

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2004/05/31/145105.aspx) suggests that it is never possible to unload assemblies from a living AppDomain as a design decision - and attempts to explain why. Up to you whether that's sufficient justification I suppose, but it does make this idea look like a non-starter.

Comment: It is a limitation of .NET. You cannot unload an assembly. If you want to unload an assembly you need to terminate whole AppDomain. That goes beyond scope of IoC container - you are looking for custom web server because AppDomain represents whole your web application.

Comment: You only can do that by yourself with AppDomain. Please take reference at here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633140/MEF-and-AppDomain-Remove-Assemblies-On-The-Fly

Comment: MEF is designed to provide extensibility, not isolation. MAF (Managed Add-In Framework) is designed to provide isolation, all the way from a single in-process AppDomain hosting the "add-in" to multiple out-of-process hosts. Judging from questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091383/can-ioc-and-the-managed-addin-framework-system-addin-work-together-with-isola) there probably isn't much demand for this functionality in IoC containers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is not. Because it is not possible to unload an assembly, only a total appdomain. THis is a .NET runtime limitation - and as every .NET IOC container has to live in the .NET runtime it can not bypass it.

If your imports are big enough isolating them in separate appdomains may be a good and viable idea.

Comment: Yeah, I knew this going in that creating a separate AppDomain was the only plausible solution, I was just wondering if someone has already blazed this trail.

Comment: Yes, many have. IIS works like that. I write an applicaiton doing that right now. It is not exactly hard and not exaclty something that is rare.

Comment: Are there any resources you can share about how you approached it?

Comment: +1 @TomTom - are you actually building real IoC that marshals all interfaces to unique AppDomains? (IIS is not really sample of IoC container - it really 2 separate parts that have very little communication between each other).

Comment: No. My use is really limited from the interfaces, at the end message queue in and out.

Comment: @TomTom - that is indeed common way (and similar to IIS/ASP.Net). Not really IoC container so.

Answer (score 3):

You can not unload assemblies in .Net without unload whole AppDomain. So the only way to allow it is to load new assemblies into new AppDomains.

While it may be possible to build such IoC container that will marshal all requests to new AppDomains for many interfaces such code would put very significant restrictions on methods/objects exposed by the interfaces. Also many .Net objects can't cross AppDomain boundary (xml, UI/controls, HTML context, database related classes).

It is significantly easier to allow ASP.Net to deal with reloading of the AppDomain.